fontawesome pro graphql query to only search icons that are active in custom subset
I'm trying to build a graphql query to search icons that are available in my fontawesome pro kit. I'm using custom subsetting, so I would like the search query to return only the icons that are available in my subset.
I'm able to search ALL icons like this:
query Search {
    search(query: "calendar", version: "6.x") {
        id
    }
}

I'm able to search my custom icons like this:
query Me {
    me {
        id
        kit(token: "xxxxxxxxx") {
            iconUploads {
                name
            }
        }
    }
}

The combination of these queries allow we to find all the icons in my kit (both my sets and the custom icons), but the problem is that the first query also returns icons that I have not selected. Instead, it returns ALL icons. How can I get a list of only the icons that I hand picked to use in my custom subset?
